# how to create different databases dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have already develop one web application in.net
Now, i have to create dynamic database as user goes on one particular screen.
Accordingly change web.config with connection string.
how i can create different databases dynamically for web application in asp.net?and change connection string?

Answer (score 0):

to change Connection String in Web.config, you can refer to the example on the following [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Programmatically-Add-or-Update-Connection-String-in-ASPNet-WebConfig-File.aspx):

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are facing with a wrong concept. Are you sure you really need many databases?
With regards to the config: it's not necessary to keep all your connection strings in a config file. You can keep them as some private variable although it's not the best pracrice. You can also store multiple connection strings.
And in the case if you really have to create some database, you can call a simple sql query.
But again: make double sure that you really need to create multiple databases.

Comment: Actually I am Working on Construction ERP So,very huge data will get inserted under one project or Site also Our Client Requirement is that when new project is get created by user at the same time create new database.so i am trying for that.....