# Using multiple dynamically created databases in project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, database-connection

After surfing on StackOverflow found out, that there are many projects that uses multiple databases. In my project I create them even dynamically. Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19266294/2041039) is given reason (Construction ERP, one database for one client) is important enough?
Can someone give pros and cons of this project structure?

Comment: I understand, that it's a some kind of evil things, but can anyone give arguments that breaks this architecture for medium scale projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole application architecture depends your project sale model.

If you host database for most clients (eg. some of them prefer to host database in their environment), I recommend to stay with one database that will cover all customers you operate.

I've worked on ERP system dedicated for two clients, database was hosted on our environment but data was separated between customers. We did it by adding one additional table "Customer" and every entity that differs for customers has foreign key to that table. If you asked me about performance, I said you that it's not a problem at all - creating proper indexes on tables, delete old unnecessary data and even deployment of some kind of caching server between application and database will deal well with it. We had an database with approx. 120GB on disk, and some tables had approx 84 mln. records. (I've also worked with database sized 2TB on disk, but it was a SharePoint database so it's a little bit different story)

Pros:

- Easiest database maintaining
- Possibility to migrate to separate database on customer's request
- Migration for one version to another takes smaller time

Cons:

- While yours database size grows, your's db server must grow too
- More complicated architecture for beginners (but seriously I'm don't know what is more complicated - generating every time new database for new customer, or implement correct solutions architecture once)
- If yours customer requests for specific solution that differs from others - you need to setup a separate environment and migrate data

And finally, according to statistics - development costs are much lower in comparison to maintaining costs, so if could reduce maintaining costs by implementing proper architecture for solution your profit from project will be greater.

Answer (score 0):

What you say in your question is that you have an application that uses many databases creating them dynamically. Now you ask why, someone recommends to use a single database.
My answer is, it depends from what you want to achieve.
Using a single database instead of many databases usually is better because opening and closing connections is one of the most time consuming tasks you can do on a PC, the modern database servers use connection pooling to use less resources and optimize the opening and closing of connections but still open and close connections are time consuming and resource consuming operations. So if You manage data in your application is better if all the data are inside a single database.
A different scenario instead can be better managed with more databases. For example, I have an application with a client installed on a PC that uses SQL Server to manage data. Normal Users access just their company database, so they need a single database.
I instead, being a consultant in many companies need to be able to connect my client to multiple databases, based on the customer where I work. So my application allows me to have multiple connection strings and use whichever one I need, but the application works on one database at a time. The final answer to the Use of single or multiple database is of course "it depends" on what your application does.
Also, the creation of tables on databases is a time and resource consuming task, so dynamically create tables is really necessary for you? Or it means just that you create the database when needed and then use it?